# How to determine "TapEnded" in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to change background color of UIView tap, I know how to catch touch events and gestures on UIView in iOS.

I can change color when `touchesBegan` fires and then change it to original color when `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled` fires.

This works fine, until user tap on UIView really fast, this can be determined by `UITapGestureRecognizer` and change background color, but I don't know how to change color after that!

I don't want to use some kind of "Timer" or similar approach.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect that the tap ended by checking its state:

Objective-C

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // change the color here
}
```

Swift

```
if recognizer.state == .Ended {
    // change the color here
}
```

Comment: it's a very good suggestion, I tried it, but because this recognizer.state is triggered at the same time recognizer fires, it prevent changing color at beginning.

Comment: But doesn't it work if you check the UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, change your color and then change it back when UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded?

Comment: No, apple indicated that this state only work for continues gestures. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. From your question it seems that you have successfully done it with following delegates of UIView.

   - touchesBegan:
   - touchesEnded:
   - touchesCancelled:
2. The second option is to use UITapGestureRecognizer which was already mentioned by you. Please try using following code in your gesture recognizer method.

**Add gesture to your view:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTap:)];

[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture ];
```

**Your gesture recognizer method**

```
-(void) viewTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
   if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
   {
      //All fingers are lifted.
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually apple indicate that this state changing is for "not continues"  gestures. :(